# How to make "transbox" full width

Tags: html, css

I want to make it stay at the very top and very left, but there's still space.

Can someone tell me how to make it full width ?

[image]

My css code

```
body
{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background : url('4163-16y6220.png');
}

.transbox 
{
background : black;
opacity : 0.2;
width : 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Example
    </title><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="transbox">Home dasdahbbjb</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post this code in jsfiddle. for better clarity

Comment: well, today the opacity is a little old, you can use background-color: rgba(64,65,65, 1) at las you can use 0.1 to 1, this will be the opacity of you color :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding` and `margin` 0  to `body`

```
body
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background : url('4163-16y6220.png');
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gen7wpkm/1/

Answer (score 3):

You need to **reset** your HTML document.
Use a reset like **[Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)**

This will reset all elements to `0`.
`margin`, `padding`, and more will set to default.

**[Here](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet)** is another reset:

```
/*
*  html5 doctor css reset | http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet
*/
html,body,div,span,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,abbr,address,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,samp,small,strong,sub,sup,var,b,i,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}
body{line-height:1}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}
nav ul{list-style:none}
blockquote,q{quotes:none}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none}
a{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}
ins{background-color:#ff9;color:#000;text-decoration:none}
mark{background-color:#ff9;color:#000;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold}
del{text-decoration:line-through}
abbr[title],dfn[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;cursor:help}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
hr{display:block;height:1px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #ccc;margin:1em 0;padding:0}
input,select{vertical-align:middle}
```

More info, here on SO: [css-reset](/questions/tagged/css-reset)

Comment: Wow, that was extreme way to solve it O.O but thnx for the answer :)

Comment: thats true always use reset, every browser has own defaults css startup

Answer (score 2):

Try making the div with `margin-left: -10px;`

or whatever suits your needs.

This isnt probably the nicest way to do it but it will do.

Here is a codepen to help.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGBGrL

Answer (score 2):

Well, all this guys only fix the problem with you code using `opacity : 0.2;` but in actuality is obsolete because you can use rgba colors [w3schools rgba examples](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp)

**Example**

Define different RGB colors with opacity:

```
#p1 {background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);}   /* red with opacity */
#p2 {background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);}   /* green with opacity */
#p3 {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);}   /* blue with opacity */
```

There are many tools on the internet that is not the most recommended use because otherwise you never learn anything, but hey here's a this is the link
[css3maker.com](http://www.css3maker.com/css-3-rgba.html)

what you can do to the top is a `div` with style transparent and a div that this under the color of the background you should go

Answer (score 1):

Only add

```
.transbox 
{
       background : black;
       opacity : 0.2;
       width : 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       position:absolute;
       top:0px;
       left:0px;
}
```